# Check if the number total appearance of the values in mysql database is odd in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, having-clause

[image]

I have a database with the user id, I want to check the total number of times each user id occurred and fetch only the ones which their total number of occurrence is odd in number.

For example, I have "Sandra" with id 2 and appears 5 times, since 5 is odd it'd fetch all data like that.
I tried

```
SELECT L_UID, count(*) as count from tenter group by L_UID order by count DESC
```

I was able to get the counts but couldn't check if they are odd or not.

Comment: is there a cause why you don't show us your code that produces the multi inserts

Comment: Just like an ecommerce where a particular user id makes multiple purchases, I want to fetch all users whose purchases that are odd in number.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the condition in the HAVING caluse:

```
SELECT L_UID, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM tenter 
GROUP BY L_UID 
HAVING count % 2 = 1
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in School you divide if by 2 and look at the rest, in Math it is called Modulo

```
SELECT L_UID, IF((count(*) %2) = 1,'odd', 'even') as count from tenter group by L_UID order by count DESC
```